# disable COMMAND+TAB app switcher in 10.15

Tags: keyboard, applications, catalina, shortcut, application-switcher

The other questions asking the same thing are from many years ago and for different versions of MacOS.

Is it possible to completely disable the COMMAND+TAB shortcut for the app switcher? I want to remove/disable the app switcher entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple: "[...] you cannot define keyboard shortcuts for general purpose tasks such as opening an app or **switching between apps**."

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-global-keyboard-shortcuts-mchlp2262/mac

But maybe you can share your specific needs so we may find a solution.

Comment: Darn. I want to make COMMAND+TAB cycle through tabs in Chrome. Oh well. I'll have to figure out something else. Might have to try Better Touch Tool or something.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan you know you can use Control+TAB right? I do it all the time, and you can also add shift to cycle backwards.

Comment: Yes; but I need/want COMMAND+TAB.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan why tho? You are the second person I see talking about this, changing basic shortcuts will lead you to have issues every time you sit on another computer or reset your system.

Comment: I have a Windows, Linux, and Mac computer all connected through a KVM. I don't want to have to code switch every time I jump between a different OS. Instead, I'd rather make all the OSs work the same -- the same keyboard shortcuts. I was trying to avoid using tools like BTT but I think I'll have to.

Comment: I don't sit on a new computer often and if I have to reset then it's just a matter of quickly re-applying my settings. I usually keep a document with 1-2-3 steps to follow after a fresh-install.

Comment: shf+cmd+{  or } will cycle through tabs in most apps, sometimes ctl+tab in some apps

Comment: One reason to disable it, as in my case, is I am having wrist pain which could be due to the need to twist the wrist left whilst pressing thumb on CMD and middle finger on tab. I do it very often, hundreds of times per day. I do not know if it's causing the pain so am experimenting with using an alternate app switcher with easier keyboard shortcut. But my habit keeps coming back to using CMD + TAB so I need to disable it to stop my habit and see if my wrist heals (or not).

Comment: @LaurenceCope wow, that is tough man. Have you tried those ergonomic keyboards? There are several options, maybe it could help you. Also, I bought a standing desk, so I can work sitting or standing, and it changed my life regarding back pain. It could also help you to change the angle of your arms.

Comment: No its a Macbook and I would first rather try seeing if not twisting my wrist whilst pressing down fixes it, than carry a second keyboard round, but be good idea to try if this does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @LaurenceCope sure, it would be better to have the option to change. That is one of the things I hate about Apple. I can do whatever I want using Windows. There are literally no restraints.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan did you have any luck making PC keyboard Ctrl+Tab cycle tabs in Chrome with swapped Cmd and Control modifiers?

Comment: No I didn't. I gave up on macOS and Windows. I moved my daily driver to Linux. :/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to force command-tab as a tab switcher *only in some applications* with Karabiner-Elements feature 'complex modifications'.

You would need a browser that you can customize the tab cycler shortcut and set it to option+tab then map your command-tab to option-tab in applications you need. (I guess you can disable the switcher entirely based on the conditions you have set)

```
{
    "description":"Use ctrl+tab as tab switcher in vscode and vivaldi",
    "manipulators":[
        {
            "conditions":[
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers":[
                        "^com.vivaldi.Vivaldi",
                        "^com.microsoft.VSCode"
                    ],
                    "type":"frontmost_application_if"
                }
            ],
            "from":{
                "key_code":"tab",
                "modifiers":{
                    "optional":[
                        "control"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to":[
                {
                    "key_code":"tab",
                    "modifiers":[
                        "option"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type":"basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions":[
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers":[
                        "^com.vivaldi.Vivaldi",
                        "^com.microsoft.VSCode"
                    ],
                    "type":"frontmost_application_if"
                }
            ],
            "from":{
                "key_code":"tab",
                "modifiers":{
                    "optional":[
                        "control",
                        "shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to":[
                {
                    "key_code":"tab",
                    "modifiers":[
                        "option",
                        "shift"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type":"basic"
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily disable or remap to whatever you want via BetterTouchTool.

```
brew install --cask bettertouchtool
```

This is my sample configuration to remap the default macOS app switcher (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) to Select the next tab in the browser:

[image: Screenshot of the Keyboard App Shortcuts dialog box showing remapped shortcuts for 'Select Next Tab' (Shift+F1) and 'Select Previous Tab' (Command+Shift+F1)]

[image: Screenshot of BetterTouchTool with the the same shortcuts]